# What files does Bluepill create on my system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bluepill

I am working with Rails 3.0.3 and Bluepill 0.0.51. I am trying to troubleshoot a situation where Bluepill is trying to start multiple instances of my ruby servers in some cases, but having trouble knowing where to start since the only files I have to look at are my ruby server .rb files and my .pill file in my rails app root folder. What are the configuration/other files that Bluepill creates on my system? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you do run a successful pill recepie it can create different files based on your configuration. If you demonize the process it will create a .pid for each process that stores a value that represents the Process ID of that process so it can shut it down. It will also create a log file and sometimes files in sock. It uses /var/run/bluepill by default but if you run it in --no-privileged mode it will want you to specify the location, preferebly in your applications folder.

It doesn't create anything to configure but rather you configure everything in the pill file. It can be tricky getting everything to work but you have to keep trying. I realize this post is old so i hope your solved it :)